# WebApi Method with single value and AngularJs $http json handling

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am encountering an issue and I ran out of ideas, I need some guidance towards the origin and/or the solution:

**Server Side**

I added the standard Microsoft `Web Api Controller` class "`ValuesController`" which looks like this:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{              
   public string Get(int id){ return "value"; }
   ...
```

**Client Side**

In my AngularJS Controller function I have a simple get

```
$http({method:'GET',url: '/api/values/1'}).success(function(data){
        $scope.value  =data;
    })
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="value" />
```

The weird thing(the issue) is that I get: "value" in my input instead of just value (no quotes).
To avoid misunderstandings, I am getting this:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

And of course the questions are: why?? and how do I fix it*?

*hopefully the answer will not be returning an object instead of a simple string :)

Comment: Your question seems related to this another one: [JSON String in response shows up with quotes](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4174/json-string-in-response-shows-up-with-quotes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the impression that this is due to security vulnerabilities in the JSON format. In the documentation of the $http service there is section called [JSON Vulnerability Protection](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) that suggests that Angular takes a few precautions to avoid an attack.

They recommend the reading of the following article: [Anatomy of a Subtle JSON Vulnerability](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/) which as far as I can see delves into a case similar to yours.

Bottom line, I think you will have to return a full JSON object and not just a string. An alternative is to make sure you are getting a JSON object, by doing

```
$scope.value = JSON.parse(value)
```

Comment: `JSON.parse()` solved a similar issue for me. The response from the server seemed fine, however it did not work on the client, until I added a call to `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred (Angular provided solution) is

`$scope.value = angular.fromJson(data);`